# Tibullus: Neu quisquam multo percussum tempora baccho Excitet

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'm having a real tough time with this passage from Tibullus 1.2 lines 3 and 4:

Neu quisquam multo percussum tempora baccho
Excitet, infelix dum requiescit amor.

Is he using 'baccho' as a synonym for alcohol?  It is also seems that 'percussum tempora' is accusative, 'percussum' would be a participle acting as an adjective that modifies 'tempora'.  'Beaten temples (on the head)' seems to be the best translation.  But who is doing the beaten?  Quisquam or the alcohol?  Alcohol I would think would be more logical.  But because 'molto baccho' is dative/ablative, I cannot translate it into anything that makes sense.  Also, the "infelix dum requiescit amor" is difficult. 'While unhappy love sleeps,' but I'm not exactly sure what T is doing here.  It's clear from line 1-2 that he is talking about himself.  So is he saying that he is now the god 'Amor' or perhaps the embodiment of love.  It's clear from the poem that he is in love but I don't say why he would say that he is love itself.  Anyway, he seems to be saying: "let no one rouse (excitet) while unhappy love sleeps" then it gets hard to complete the translation.  Should it be: struck to the temples by copious alcohol???  Or perhaps 'with temples beaten with copious alochol'  But if the second is true I don't see why 'tempora' would be accusative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, *quisquam* is the subject of *excitet*, *percussum* the direct object (adjective functioning as a noun; it can't be an adjective with *tempora* as that's plural). *Baccho* is a dative of agent to go with *percussum*, *multo* is just an adverb, *tempora* is a [Greek accusative](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/idiomatic-accusatives#three-nine-seven-b) (accusative of specification).

My literal translation:

> And let no-one rouse him who is much beaten about the temples by Bacchus, while love rests unfortunate.

Obviously Bacchus does stand in for the effects of the unmixed wine mentioned in the first two lines, yes. The last bit is just flowery, I wouldn't try to interpret it too hard; the grammar is clear.

Comment: I think the one who is *percussus* and whom you shouldn't *excitāre* is the same as the one who *requiēscit*, namely *amor*. The poem is autoreferential - Tibullus puts his love pains to sleep with wine.

Comment: I do think grammatically multo is modifying Baccho. As a pure adverb, multum would be expected. Of course, there's a lot of freedom in how one renders that in English.

Comment: Also, Baccho is ablative of instrument, not dative. Cf. Livy: [Hannibal] femur tragula 
grauiter ictus

Comment: @Kingshorsey: As to *multo*, I think it could be either the adverb *multo* (which I believe can be used instead of *multum*, but I do think you are right that this is uncommon), or an adjective modifying *Baccho* made countable. As to the case of *Baccho*, why do you think it should be ablative? A dative of agent is not so rare with past participles? An ablative of agent without a praepsition is rare with a person?

Comment: @Cerberus I don't think Tibullus is literally referring to Bacchus, but is using the name metaphorically, and therefore is treating it as an inanimate instrument. Cf. this other Tibullan passage: Care puer, madeant generoso pocula baccho

He's talking about a hangover, which is caused by a lot of wine, i.e., multo Baccho. I cannot believe Tibullus wrote multo ... Baccho and didn't expect them to be read together.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that (probs bc. the entire translation as it was confused me). There's no shadow of a doubt that it goes with *Bacchō* - *multō* like other ablative-accusative quantifier pairs is never used adverbially to mean "a lot", but only in comparisons: *multō citius, melius, pulchrius*. The singular use of quantity words is quite ordinary in Latin, granted it confers a poetic flair in many cases (such as here).—Incidentally you have two divine personifications here: Amor gets smacked across the side of the head by Bacchus. And yes, it's not grammatically personal so instrumental.

Comment: Btw "the dative of agent" is a grossly misleading and erroneous traditional name for the specific case of the Dative expressing the theta role of Experiencer (*mihi placet*) being used with some deontic (modal) expressions: *mihi necesse est, mihi faciundum est* ("the need to do exists in relation to me"). The Agent is expressed with ā + Ablative: *ā mē faciundum est* ("I am the one who must do"). With past participles the Dative would mean "as far as I'm concerned" if it's adjectival: *ille est mihi perditus* - and if verbal with Dative verbs, "to me": *ille est mihi restitūtus, dōnātus...*

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian [Please review](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-agent), especially section 375a. The gerundive's dative of agent (about which I'm inclined to agree with you) is not identical with the dative of agent that goes with other verbal forms.

Comment: Additionally, *multo* as an adverb is indeed most common with comparatives, but [by no means restricted to them](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23multo%23). The use of *bacchus* to literally (as opposed to metaphorically) mean 'wine' is certainly considerably dodgier.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134094/discussion-on-answer-by-cairnarvon-tibullus-neu-quisquam-multo-percussum-tempor).

Answer (score 3):

Cairnarvon has addressed the Greek accusative, so I'll limit myself to the phrase multo ... baccho. Sometimes the name of a god is used to refer poetically to some physical thing with which that god is associated. Here, baccho just means wine, and *multo percussum tempora baccho* means "a person pounded in the temples by a lot of wine."

Some parallel passages for confirmation

Tibullus, Carmina 3.6.1:

```
Care puer, madeant generoso pocula baccho

Dear boy, keep the cups brimming over with "bacchus" of good vintage
```

Vergil, *Eclogae* 5.65-69:

```
... en quattuor aras: 
ecce duas tibi, Daphni, duas altaria Phoebo.    
pocula bina nouo spumantia lacte quotannis
craterasque duo statuam tibi pinguis oliui,
et multo in primis hilarans conuiuia Baccho 

Lo, four altars:
Lo, two for you, Daphne, two high altars for Phoebus.
Two cups yearly frothing with fresh milk 
And two bowls of rich olive oil I will set out for you, 
and, most importantly, enlivening the feast with lots of "Bacchus"
```

Propertius, Elegia 1.3:

```
ebria cum multo traherem vestigia Baccho

while I was dragging my steps intoxicated from lots of "Bacchus"
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.